# How to add the output in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

lets say I am checking if the connect established with particular port.

```
nc -zv 162.147.191.141 8080 2>&1  |grep  -w 8080;

output- 
Connection to 162.147.191.141 port 8080 [tcp/*] succeeded!

nc -zv 162.147.191.141 80 2>&1  |grep  -w 80;

output-
nc: connectx to 162.147.191.141 port 80 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

So now I have a scenario if connection established with particular port(ex- 8080 or 80) then add the ip to the output file.

Here $? I have used to see connection is succeed or failed .
If connection will succeeded then add the ip to the out.txt file.

how I will extract ip[162.247.241.14] in **then** statement to write to the output file ?

```
nc -zv 162.247.241.14 8080 2>&1  |grep  -w 8080; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; 
then ??
 ; fi
```

I will use this code later to implement in larger scale.

```
port1=80
port2=8080

for host in `cat hostfile.txt`
do
nc -zv $host $portno1; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then ??  >>output.txt
nc -zv $host $portno2; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then ??  >>output.txt
done
```

Comment: `if output=$(...); then echo "Received output: $output"; ...` -- you don't extract the output in the `then`; after you store it in the `if` you can _use_ it in the `then`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Can you please modify the code in for loop?

Comment: First, _don't_ use `if [ $? -eq 0 ]` -- see [Why is testing `$?` to see if a command succeeded or not an antipattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern). I'll add a proper answer for the rest.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I tried this but it is not writing the ip to the output file.

MacBook-Air  % if output=$(nc -zv 162.247.241.14 8080 </dev/null); then printf '%s\n' "$output" >>output.txt; fi
Connection to 162.247.241.14 port 8080 [tcp/*] succeeded!
-MacBook-Air % cat output.txt

Comment: Note that success and failure messages aren't output. If you want _error logs_ to go to the file you need to capture stderr, not stdout; what the code currently writes to the file is any actual data sent by the remote server; as far as I could tell from the question that was what you wanted.

Comment: it is not writing anything to the output file.
 I want when the connection is succeed then it will add the ip to the output file.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please refresh if necessary to make sure you have the latest copy, and run the code it contains **exactly** as currently given.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255842/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-nimi).

Answer (score 2):

Consider something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ports=( 80 8080 )

while IFS= read -r host; do
  for port in "${ports[@]}"; do
    if output=$(nc -zv "$host" "$port" </dev/null 2>&1); then
      printf '%s %s %q\n' "${host}" "${port}" "${output}" >&3
    fi
  done
done <hostfile.txt 3>>output.txt
```

Note:

- We're using a bash shebang, instead of starting our script with `sh`; this ensures that extended features like arrays are available.
- We're reading the input file with a [BashFAQ #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) `while read` loop; see [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) for background on why this is a safer practice.
- We're only storing *one* variable with an array of ports; there's no reason to store `port1` and `port2` as several variables when we can have a single `ports` variable.
- We're attaching `nc`'s stdin to `/dev/null` so it can't block trying to read the script's current stdin.
- We're storing the stdout and stderr (the latter selected by `2>&1`) of nc in a variable named `output`.
- Using `3>>output.txt` lets us open `output.txt` *only once* for the whole loop; subsequently, using `>&3` on a specific `echo` command directs content to that already-open file descriptor -- much faster than creating a whole new file handle for every single write.

Comment: what is done <hostfile.txt 3>>output.txt ?

Comment: `<hostfile.txt` connects file descriptor 0 -- stdin -- to `hostfile.txt` so that for the duration of the loop we're reading to the file. `3>>output.txt` connects file descriptor 3 to append to `output.txt`, so any time we run a command with `>&3` that command's output is written to that file. Both of these redirections are scoped to the entire `while read` loop -- stdin and stdout are modified when the loop starts and put back when it exits.

Comment: We are reading host in while loop in the beginning and adding hostfile.txt at the end.
Will it able to take the hostname?

Comment: As I said before, the redirections are scoped to _the whole loop_. Just because it's written at the end doesn't mean it doesn't apply to the entire thing. Please follow the link and read BashFAQ #1 if you have questions.

Comment: why %q is used?

Comment: `%q` makes newlines, nonprintable characters, and whatever other random junk shows up in output or error messages printable instead of sending it to the file (and thus the reader's terminal) as-is.

Comment: @NIMI, ...the other point of that is to ensure that you always get exactly one line of output per IP/port combo, even if nc writes errors that span multiple lines.